# rxjs: conditionally mapping a stream

Tags: rxjs

An Ngrx selector returns a boolean value from store:

`store.select(isInitialized)`

The initial value is 'false', but after some time (after an async operation has been completed) the returned value will be true.

Once the observable emits true there should be a short delay before emission and the stream should complete:

`emit false -> ...(async operation ends) -> (intentional delay before emitting true) -> emit true -> complete`

The code below does the trick by switching to either `of(true).pipe(delay(3000))` or `of(false)` and later completing the stream with `takeWhile`:

```
this.initialized$ = store.select(isInitialized).pipe(

    switchMap((value: boolean) => {

        if (value)
            return of(true).pipe(delay(3000));
        return of(false);

    }),
    takeWhile(value => !value, true)

);
```

I'm looking for a more elegant way of achieving the same by using different operators instead of an if-condition inside a switchMap?

Comment: I think your solution is clear, easy to read and understand, easier (at least for me) than those suggested by the other answers. The answers I have seen, rightly answering your question, show alternative approaches. I find such approaches less clear to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the operator `delayWhen` to apply the delay conditionally like this:

```
this.initialized$ = store.select(isInitialized).pipe(
  delayWhen((value) => timer(value ? 3000 : 0)),
  ...
)
```

Or use this alternative if you need to execute the `false` case synchronously:

```
delayWhen((value) => (value ? timer(3000) : of('now')))
```

> the 'now' value is not relevant, you just need to return a sync observable that emits something for the false condition.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think akotech's answer is the one I'd go for, but just to give a different approach:

```
const [true$, false$] = partition(initialized$.pipe(share()), Boolean);

merge(
  true$.pipe(delay(3000)),
  false$
)
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qrq2no?devToolsHeight=33&file=index.ts).

This approach uses [partition](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/partition) to split the stream in 2 different stream, and apply a delay on the `true` stream but not the `false` one, then merges them.

Note the necessary use of `share` (or not necessary but recommended). partition will subscribe twice the original stream. In your case, with a stream from your store it doesn't matter because everything is memoized and subscribing twice will be blazingly fast as it'll just take a value from the cache. But if you were to use any other stream for the input of the `partition`, using `share` would definitely be a good idea to avoid computing things twice if you've got costly operations in your stream.

Once again, I'd go for akotech's answer. Just sharing this one for fun.